# "Some unicode characters can't be saved in the current codepage" using Cyrillic in C

Tags: c, windows

I am struggling to make the text in my program appear in Bulgarian using Cyrillic.

I have tried `'SetConsoleOutputCP(1251)'` as well as `'SetConsoleCP(1251)'`, but neither of them worked.  I am using VS2018 and the file is saved as `file.c`.  When trying to compile the warning appears:

```
"Some unicode characters can't be saved in the current codepage."
```

Code

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<Windows.h>
#include<string.h>

SetConsoleOutputCP(1251)
int i;

int main() {
  i=choice();
  printf("%d\n",i);
  system("pause");
  return 0;
}

int choice(void) {
  printf("избор\n");
  printf("1.четене от файл и запис\n");
  printf("2.четене и извеждане на резултата\n");
  printf("3.четене от клавиатура и запис\n");
  printf("4.четене от клавиатура и извеждане\n ");
  printf("5.изход\n");

  do {
    scanf_s("%d",&i);
  } while (i < 1 || i > 5);
  return i;
}
```

Comment: what encoding is your c file saved in?

Comment: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cwchar/wprintf/

Comment: Don't you want to use unicode for that?

Comment: Shouldn't you be calling `SetConsoleOutputCP` not redefining it as a macro?

Comment: @usr2564301 a warning pops out-Some unicode characters can't be saved in the corrent codepage.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I have edited the code as well as the question.

Comment: Thank you for the effort! I'm not personally in a position to help with a problem that's only reproducible on Windows, but since this now complies with the MCVE definition (and is otherwise a clear, answerable, useful question), my close vote is retracted.

Comment: you need save self src file as unicode or utf-8

Answer (score 2):

If your system is set to use ANSI code page other than 1251, and you save the file in a different code page, or in Unicode (either UTF8 or UTF16), the compiler will not recognize the Cyrillic characters.

So you have to save your *.c file in code page 1251 as shown in the image below.

[image]

A better solution is to save the file in Unicode (UTF8 is preferred), then use wide string functions throughout the program. However, `_setmode` is Visual Studio specific. You cannot use `printf` and calling `_setmode(_fileno(stdin), _O_U16TEXT);`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <io.h> 
#include <fcntl.h>

int main(void)
{
    _setmode(_fileno(stdout), _O_U16TEXT);
    _setmode(_fileno(stdin), _O_U16TEXT);
    wprintf(L"1.четене от файл и запис + English\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: For `print` to the console, we can use UTF-8 after `SetConsoleOutputCP(CP_UTF8)`. I don't recommend this for Windows 7 and earlier, since older implementations of the console return the number of code points written instead of the proper number of bytes written, which causes C standard I/O to print a trailing sequence of garbage if a print has non-ASCII characters.

Comment: That said, we can also support `wprintf` in this case since VC++ now allows `setlocale(LC_ALL, ".utf8")`. But the implementation is inefficient. The file stream encodes the wide string with the UTF-8 local encoding. Then when the stream buffer is flushed, the low I/O `_write` needlessly does a double translation from UTF-8 to UTF-8 (i.e. from the locale encoding to UTF-16, then to the console output encoding).